# How to split a sentence in words while keeping some compound expressions containing white spaces?

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a String on white spaces but I need to ignore some compound keywords which contain white spaces.  For example, I have a String as following,

```
String testCase = "The patient is currently being treated for Diabetes with Thiazide diuretics";
```

I need the String to be split but need `Thiazide diuretics` as a whole compound expression after

```
String[] array = testCase.split(" ");
```

The result needs to be as following:

> ```
> The
> patient
> is
> currently
> being
> treated
> for
> Diabetes
> with 
> Thiazide diuretics
> ```

How to do that ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to tokenize the string beyond just a simple split. Maybe look into what max chomping is (in tokenization), as well as defining a list of "drugs".

Comment: Change your string to String testCase = "The patient is currently being treated for Diabetes with Thiazidediuretics";

Comment: Cant do that, the drug name comes as parameter inside the method

Comment: Get the index of " " before  `Thiazide diuretics` and then split the string from that index.

Comment: Then your job is probably significantly easier. Just run through the string and see if you found a drug in the upcoming N words, and if not, eat the word and continue.

Comment: I need it like this way as when writing the test cases, someone put additional characters after the word say, Thiazide diureticssdsd and then, it will fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to deal with the regex directly in this case, `.split()` is not fit* for your purpose.

```
String s = "The patient is currently being treated for Diabetes with Thiazide diuretics";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:Thiazide diuretics)\\b|\\S+").matcher(s);
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    result.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(result);
// [The, patient, is, currently, being, treated, for, Diabetes, with, Thiazide diuretics]
```

---

Note: Technically it is possible to do so with `.split()` using lookarounds:

```
String s = "Thiazide not-a-keyword diuretics and Thiazide diuretics keyword";

String[] result = s.split("(?<!Thiazide) | (?!diuretics)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
// [Thiazide, not-a-keyword, diuretics, and, Thiazide diuretics, keyword]
```

But this doesn't scale when you have got more keywords. Try to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
String[] splits(String source,String drugName) {
    int pos=source.indexOf(drugName);
    if (pos!=-1) {
        String[] internal=source.substring(0,pos).split(" ");
        String[] rest=splits(source.substring(pos+drugName.length()).trim(),drugName);
        String[] result=new String[internal.length+rest.length+1];
        System.arraycopy(internal,0,result,0,internal.length);
        result[internal.length]=drugName;
        System.arraycopy(rest,0,result,internal.length+1,rest.length);
        return result;
    }
    return source.split(" ");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try to use some regular expression, like

```
static String[] mysplit(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!Thiazide) | (?!diuretics)");
    return p.split(str);
}
```

Comment: whats n here ? can you write complete code using the example I have ?